# Encoding unicode with python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8, python-2.x

I’m trying to understand how encoding unicode works in python2.7, so far it’s easy to find the solution but I haven’t found any clear explanation as what is going on here.  Here is an example.

#### The introduction

We have a unicode variable we received, called **filter_type**
`filter_type = u'some_välüe'`.

We put this into a dict and pass this into the *python library* **urllib.urlencode**.

Like so:

```
urllib.urlencode({"param:" ..., "filter_type": filter_type}
```

#### This issue.

Inside `urllib.urlencode` it loops around the data given to it and wraps the keys and values into the `str()` builtin function to get a string representation of each key and value before encoding it into a url.

We get an error similar to the following:
`{UnicodeEncodeError}'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 42: ordinal not in range(128)`.

You get this same error by doing `str(u'some_välüe')`.

So after some research and digging into this it looks like when you wrap unicode values in the `str()` it tries to encode the value into the default encoding that is set. (my assumption)

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
ascii
```

#### The solution.

So we can fix this by encoding these unicode strings with **utf-8**.
`filter_type = u'some_välüe'.encode('utf-8')`.

#### The question.

But here is the question. Before i mentioned that `urllib.urlencode` wraps keys and values into the `str()` function.

These values are already encoded now, so..

1. What does str() does in this case now?
2. Does the representation of a unicode object change when it’s encoded to **utf-8**?
3. If it does why did `str()` try to encode the unicode object to ascii (default) in the first place.

Comment: Because in Python 2, `str` is equivalent to a bytes-string, and distinct from the `unicode` data-type. So yes, the representation changes. A unicode object is a sequence of unicode code points, a `str` object is essentially a sequence of bytes. You encode the unicode object into a `str` object, and they are now of a different type. `str(x)` tries to encode a unicode object because it *must* do that if you want a `str` and not a `unicode` object. when you call `str` on a `str` object, it simply returns the original `str` object.

Comment: @JoshLee Python 2/3 questions should always include a generic [python]

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807985/python-write-file-dealing-with-encode/39808990#39808990) related to encoding sheds some light on `unicode` ans `str` in Python 2